# Determine whether the given function is continuous or not.

Tags: continuity, solution-verification

> Determine whether the given function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}  x   &\text{ if } x\text{ is rational }\\
>           1-x  &\text{ if } x \text{ is irrational.}\end{cases}$$ is continuous or not.

Assume the function is continuous and take $x=x_1$ if $x$ is rational otherwise $x=x_2$ then we should have:

**($1$)**$$\lim_{x \to x_1}f(x)=f(x_1) $$ 
**($2$)**$$\lim_{x \to x_2}f(x)=f(x_2) $$

**($1$)** $$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists\delta_1>0, \left(\left|x-x_1\right|<\delta_1\Longrightarrow \left|f(x)-f(x_1) \right|<\epsilon\right)$$

**($2$)** $$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists\delta_2>0,\left(\left|x-x_2\right|<\delta_2\Longrightarrow \left|f(x)-f(x_2)\right|<\epsilon\right)$$

take $\epsilon=\frac{1}{4}$ then we have:

$$\left|f(x)-x \right|\le\left|f\left(x\right)\right|+\left|x\right|<\frac{1}{4}$$

$$\left|f(x)-1+x\right|\le\left|f\left(x\right)\right|+\left|x-1\right|\le\left|f\left(x\right)\right|+\left|x\right|+\left|1\right|<\frac{5}{4}$$

On the other hand :
$$1=\left|f\left(x\right)+x-f\left(x\right)-x+1\right|\le\left|f\left(x\right)+x\right|+\left|-f\left(x\right)-x+1\right|\le\left|f\left(x\right)\right|+\left|x\right|+\left|f\left(x\right)\right|+\left|x\right|+\left|1\right|<\frac{1}{4}+\frac{5}{4}=\frac{3}{2}$$

Hence  $1<\frac{3}{2}$, although I tried to reach a contradiction,I did not get that and my proof now shows the function is continuous everywhere.
but clearly the only point for which the function has a limit at is $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and the limit is the same as the value of the function for
 $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I don't think that works. For starters, where do the $\delta$s come in? Also, this argument would show that $f$ is discontinuous everywhere, but that's not true. It has at least one point of continuity.

Comment: Why do you claim "$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists\delta>0,\forall x\in D_f \left(\left|x-x_1\right|<\delta\Longrightarrow \large\left|f(x)-x \right|<\epsilon\right)$"  What role does $x_1$ play in the equation.  By definition $|f(x)-f(x_1)| < \epsilon$ but you have $|f(x) - x| < \epsilon$.  On what do you base this?  ANd not you *never* used the wether $x$ is rational or irrational.

Comment: " is continuous and take x=x1 if x is rational otherwise x=x2 th"  $x$ is supposed to be a variable.  you can't assume it is rational or irrational or have a set value.  In the next line you say "$\forall x$".  You can say for all $x$ when you've committed $x$ to be one specific value.

Comment: Can you write down your idea in words (without epsilons and deltas)? There is geomettic intuition behind these things that you need to understand: once you have a good idea of what's happening, *then* translate to epsilons and deltas and fill in any remaining holes in the reasoning.

Comment: Note:  "$f$ is continuous".  Isn't an all or nothing statement.  There might be points were it is continuous and there might be points where it isn't.  Spoiler alert:  There is one point where it *is* continuous.

Comment: fleablood,can you proof it,actually I think my whole proof is wrong

Answer (score 1):

**An Idea to prove the above:**
Assuming that between 2 rational numbers there exist some irrational numbers we may state that for some rational number $x=a$ other than 1/2.
If we look for the value of the function at that point, we can see it's $f(x)=a$ but when we do a minor increment in $x$, before reaching another rational number, it would go through an irrational number, which is greater than $a$ by an infinitesimal, we may say this irrational number as $a^+$
if we are to evaluate $f(a^+)$ it is $1-a^+$ which is approximately $1-a$ (slightly smaller than it), and $1-a\neq a$ since we choose $a\neq 1/2$.
$a$ and $a^+$ are infinitely close to each other (on x axis) but $f(a)$ and $f(a^+)$ are significantly apart, Hence $f(x)$ is **discontinuous** everywhere except $x=1/2$ as pointed out by @fleablood.

Comment: I think that is a satisfactory line to think of, If any issues are there, It would be kind to address them to me. Thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

In any neighborhood of $x$, you will find function values as close as you want to $x$ and to $1-x$. So unless $x=1-x$, continuity is broken.